# mysql_num_rows null

Tags: php, sql, mysql-workbench

Hello guys i'm doing a normal select to db, but the mysql_num_rowsis  null and i don't know why, i have 7 rows with the select.

If u detect the problem, tell me.

Really thx.

Here the code:

```
function get_bd_idusuario($usuario){

  $id_usuario = 0;

  //Coger datos a partir del usuario
  $sql="SELECT u.id_usuario
       FROM bd_tecnicos.usuarios AS u 
       WHERE u.usuario='".mysql_real_escape_string($usuario)."';";
  $query=mysql_query($sql,CONECTAR_BD_TECNICOS);

  //Si existe el usuario -- guardar su id
  if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0) $id_usuario = $row[0];

  return $id_usuario;

}

echo (get_bd_idusuario(test));
```

Comment: Try to echo the num rows before the if condition. like this :-echo 'Num Rows='.mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: ; is not an issue in this case. @Mr.Engineer

Comment: You're calling `mysql_free_result()` before returning. Store the number of rows in a variable, free all the memory associated with `$query` and then return the variable value.

Comment: Where are the comments about `mysql_*` being deprecated?

Comment: Okey SOLVED, i dont remember to put the $row=mysql_fetch_row($query);
Thank all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `mysql_free_result($query)` will free the memory related to `$query`. So any functions after this, related to `$query` won't return any value.

Quoted from the documentation of `mysql_free_result` :

> mysql_free_result() only needs to be called if you are concerned about
>   how much memory is being used for queries that return large result
>   sets.   All associated result memory is automatically freed at the end
>   of the script's execution.

Comment: @SebasBejenaru..You have to fetch the query result using any mysql functions like `mysql_fetch_row` , then return it.